# Spring cloud Netflix - properties instead of yml

Tags: properties, yaml, spring-cloud, netflix-zuul

I'm trying to use application.properties file instead of yml. However my configurations are not picked up by spring-boot. Are the configurations diffrent for yml and .properties?

In yml

```
zuul:
  ignoredServices: "*"
```

I made it like this in application.properties

```
zuul.ignoredServices=*
```

Comment: Have you tried with single quotes? I've never had a problem with it.

Comment: Same as spencer.  I am forced right now to use properties files instead of yml and have not had any issues.  "*" or '*' should work if * does not

Answer (score 0):

reverse, the "zuul.ignoredServices=*" worked fine for me.